# Convert byte data to string output like in hex editor

Tags: c#, hex, hex-editors

I’m looking for method that will return string representation of byte data just like hex editor can.
It should have one parameter which is `byte[]` and returns `string` like the following:
[image: Like it should be]

This method should handle escape characters, nulls and align text properly.
I want to use it in `Debug.WriteLine()`.
Please help me with this! Thanks!

Update:
Ok. Thank you all guys. Here is a link for a ready to use solution http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.fr/2008/04/c-file-hex-dump-application.html by Darin Dimitrov

Comment: I think you need to clarify a bit. You have two answers that, while correct, answer different questions. Are you trying to get the Hex display or the Plain Text from a byte[]? Both?

Comment: @vcsjones `string representation of byte data`. myne analyze the byte and return the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx) method:

```
public static string ToString(byte[] buffer)
{
    return BitConverter.ToString(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Yes. But I need ASCII representation after each 16 bytes. Like this.
41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 00 41 41 41 41      AAAAAAAAAAA.AAAA
59 59 59 00 59 59 59 59 59 59 59 59 59 59 53 59      YYY.YYYYYYYYYYSY

Comment: Try this: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.fr/2008/04/c-file-hex-dump-application.html

Comment: @DarinDimitrov is that your blog ?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
  byte[] b1 = ...

  string h = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b1);
```

Comment: This is not what needed. It will return just one simple string where all bytes will be converted to its char representation. Example : “  \r� �\0\a �(C��\a9��s�p��T?�m.K�9 ��y ΪM| ”

Comment: @NazarGrynko try with ASCII. this command should return the string representation of the byte. try with System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b1);.

Comment: @NazarGrynko change to *ASCII*

Comment: Yes I know. But I need it to be formatted like in screenshot I post.
Every line should consist of 16 characters of HEX (b1[0].ToString(“X2”)) than 16 characters of char (this is what Encoding.UTF8. GetString and Encoding.ACSII.GetSting returns). And at the end of a line ‘\n’